# Hiding Google Maps JavaScript API key on React app with Node.js server worth it?

Tags: node.js, react-native, google-maps-api-3, google-api, api-key

I am writing my first React app where I am dealing with Google's API for the first time as well.

Given the specific architecture of Google Maps API and what I have read from the official Google Maps API documentation, it seems like Google is ok with developers using the API key on the front-end and protecting those keys with restrictions and along with the setup of .env files.

Originally, I really wanted to build a node.js server-side to fetch the data to render and inject it into the front-end. I have read multiple people suggesting this, but once I go into looking on how to do this I quite haven't found anyone showing how to do this.

I just need the opinion of anyone that has experience in using the Google Maps API in React. It is important to mention I am doing this project so that I can place it in my personal portfolio like GitHub and Heroku.

Is it worth it to build a server for this case of hiding my API keys?

What are good resources or ideas I can look into that will help me to learn how to fetch the data needed on the backend to display a map on the front end.

Should I use React Server Components?

Should I abandon the google-map-react npm package that I am currently using and do it directly with the Google Maps JavaScript API npm package?

Comment: In short, storing API keys for google services on server is completely pointless in your case. API key isn't secret as you already mentioned, important is to restrict access properly in google console for each API key. Moreover even if you stored these keys on server, you have to fetch them and it makes them easily accessible from mobile app again.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidFutera never got to thank you for this answer that helped me understand this aspect of security with public keys